# Iterating through characters of a string stored in a vector to replace characters C++

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, vector

So we got an optional assignment in our C++ class. The assignment is basically this:

```
Write a program that holds a string of at least 8 words.
    Do the following:

    1.  Replace the letters of first word with '?'
    2.  Turn the letters of the last word to uppercase
```

We did not yet study vectors in our class.

When I first read the assignment, storing the strings to a vector seemed like a good idea so I went with it.

To replace the characters with a '?' I used a for loop. I know that this would not work if I only had to change only certain characters or every other character to a '?'.

My issue is with converting chars of a string to uppercase.
My thought process was: for loop iterates through all chars in the last word, if the char is lowercase it gets turned to uppercase, if it is already uppercase it does not change.

I believe that my approach could work for this problem, I just maybe did not express myself correctly or I made a silly error somewhere. Could anyone assist me or push me in the right direction? 
What other options are there to iterate through all chars of a string stored in a vector? Is there another approach that might work better for this? Thank you for your time.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cctype> 
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string>words;

//stores words to vector words
void storeWords()
{
    cout << "Input 8 words: " << endl;
    string s = " ";
    for(int i=0; i<=7; i++)
    {
        cin >> s;
        words.push_back(s);
    }
}
//prints our words
void printWords()
{
    cout << "\n Words stored in vector: " << endl;
    for (const string s : words)
        cout << s << endl;
}

//replaces chars of the first word with a '?' sign
void replace1(vector<string>&v)
{
    cout << "\nReplaced characters of the first word " << words[0] << " with '?'" << endl;
    for (char c : words[0])
        cout << "?";
}

void replace2(vector<string>&v)
{
    for (char c : words[7])
    {
        if(islower(c))
            c = toupper(c);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << words[7]<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    storeWords();
    printWords();
    replace1(words);
    replace2(words);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't just iterate over string, from the start and from the end doing the appropriate changes until first whitespace character? As for your question, you're missing `&` in the for-loops to bind your `c` variable to actual value in the string instead of copying it.

Comment: yr code doesnt do what the assignment says. It says "Write a program that holds a string of at least 8 words." , it doesnt say 'ask for 8 words'. You need to read one line (getline) spilt up the words and identify the first and last ones

Comment: replace1 seems like a cheat, you have not modified the stored string.

Comment: pass the individual words into the replace functions, not the whole vector, this makes those functions more general purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c = toupper(c)` will assign `c` the uppercase value. However, changing `c` will not change what's inside `words[7]`. You can get around this by referencing the char directly (`char &c`).

```
void replace2(vector<string>&v)
{
    for (char &c : words[7]) {
        c = toUpper(c);
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << words[7]<<endl;
}
```

Also note that your requirements are to hold a string of **at least** 8 words. So `words[7]` will probably end up looking like `words[words.size() - 1]`.

Comment: this seems correct to me - somebody else downvotes with no comment tho

Comment: Wow. I saw this as the other kind of `for` loop, and then you changed it... to match my answer...

Comment: @c650 It's been awhile since I've done c++. I actually saw your answer after this edit. I saw someone in the comments mention this fix. It was clearly better than my previous example of creating local copies, so yes, I did edit my answer. Still gave you the +1. :)

Answer (score 2):

This

```
for (char c : words[7])
```

Should be:

```
for (char& c : words[7])
```

The first version modifies a local variable, while the second changes the actual characters in `words[7]`.

The little ampersand (`&`) makes `c` a reference to a certain character in `words[7]`, allowing you to change `c` as you would `words[7][some_i]`.

Also, I should add that your `replace` functions do not need that `vector` argument.

[Ideone Example with that change](http://ideone.com/069uTB)